# Unable to login on first attempt

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I had built a register and a login page. When I register and try to login immediately, it works. But if I try it again after restarting my XAMPP, it won't log in.
Any suggestions?
Here is my login code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION["logging"] && $_SESSION["logged"])
{
    print_secure_content();
}
else
{
    if (!$_SESSION["logging"])
    {
        $_SESSION["logging"] = true;
        loginform();
    }
    else if ($_SESSION["logging"])
    {
        $number_of_rows = checkpass();
        if ($number_of_rows == 1)
        {
            $_SESSION[user] = $_GET[userlogin];
            $_SESSION[logged] = true;
            print "<h1>you have loged in successfully</h1>";
            print_secure_content();
        }
        else
        {
            print "wrong pawssword or username, please try again";
            loginform();
        }
    }
}

function loginform()
{
    print "please enter your login information to proceed with our site";
    print("<table border='2'><tr><td>username</td><td><input type='text' name='userlogin' size'20'></td></tr><tr><td>password</td><td><input type='password' name='password' size'20'></td></tr></table>");
    print "<input type='submit' >";
    print "<h3><a href='registerform.php'>register now!</a></h3>";
}

function checkpass()
{
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("konjam_disc", $conn);
    $sql = "select * from users where name='$_GET[userlogin]' and password='$_GET[password]'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
    return mysql_num_rows($result);
}
```

****** EDIT ******

This is the error that I'm receiving when I go to the login page:

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session
>   cookie - headers already sent by (output started at
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/demo/admin/new/index.php:8) in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/demo/admin/new/index.php on line
>   9
>
> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session
>   cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/demo/admin/new/index.php:8) in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/demo/admin/new/index.php on line
>   9

Comment: Not that it really matters but I would change $_SESSION[logged] to $_SESSION['logged'] to avoid logged being a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Horrible code and based on what's all missing to find the culprit I assume you never expect `$number_of_rows` to be higher than `1`.

Comment: If you limit the results that's not necessary but would indeed be a nice addition

Comment: I think it was obvious: make it `if( $number_of_rows>= 1 )`

Comment: @AmigoJack: I did make the changes. I get the error that I've edited in the question and I'm still unable to login if I close & open the browser and try to login. :-/

Comment: Read the message carefully: it is speaking of the file `demo/admin/new/index.php` and lines `8` and `9`, which I don't see in your question.

Comment: I got the error solved. I had opened the html before the <?php. I just put session_start(); before opening the html. Such a silly mistake. :-P
Thank you for the help @AmigoJack